# Checking if each values in list are identical to another list one by one. (Python 3)

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, for-loop, boolean

For example, we have 2 lists:

```
list_1 = [12, 3, 45, 2, 50]
list_2 = [6, 3, 30, 5, 50]
```

As we can see, we have 2 identical values in both lists. I'm currently trying to figure out a code that would check each value in the list if both are identical by order, and it will return either False or True. (checks if the first value of each list are identical. In this case, they check if 12 and 6 is identical first, and since they're not identical, it'll return False. THey they check the next one, if 3 and 3 is identical, and since it's identical, they'll return True.)

It would be nice if someone's willing to help me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can use a for loop to achieve this. (I know that this method is old school and you can achieve the same using one-liners by using map() and all() function )

I am writing the full code first. Then I will explain each steps.

(I am assuming that the lists will have equal number of elements.)

Code:-

```
list_1 = [12, 3, 45, 2, 50]
list_2 = [12, 3, 45, 2, 50]

length = len(list_1)                    # STEP 1


for i in range(0, length):              # STEP 2
    if list_1[i] != list_2[i]:
        print(False)
    else:
        print(True)
```

**Step 1**

Identify the length of the list. This can be done by `len()` function. `len(list_1)` will return the length of list_1

**Step 2**

Iterate through each element in the first list and compare it with the corresponding element in the second list. If they are different then print `False` or else print `True`

```
for i in range(0, length):
    if list_1[i] != list_2[i]:
        print(False)
    else:
        print(True)
```

Answer (score 1):

A manual method to check and compare each value of the list manually.
list_1 = [12, 3, 45, 2, 50]
list_2 = [6, 3, 30, 5, 50]

```
if(len(list_1) == len(list_1)):
    for i in range(0,len(list_1)):
        print(list_1[i] == list_2[i])
else:
    print(False) #note that If this line is executed we will get only one output
```

This is the result:
False
True
False
False
True

(EDITED)

Comment: No need of the inner conditionals. It could just be `print(list_1[i] == list_2[i])`

Comment: Absolutely! Thanks Niel. It would make the code more efficient

Answer (score 0):

You can use `all` + `zip()`
Then you can compare them with `==`.

From the [docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html):

> `all(iterable)`:
> Return True if all elements of the iterable are true (or if the iterable is empty).

> `zip(*iterables)`;
> Make an iterator that aggregates elements from each of the iterables.

```
list_1 = [12, 3, 45, 2, 50]
list_2 = [6, 3, 30, 5, 50]

def check_lists(l1,l2):
    return all(x==y for x,y in zip(l1,l2))

print (check_lists(list_1,list_2))
```

alternatively, you can directly compare them by

```
print(list_1==list_2)
```

Answer (score 0):

> In this case, they check if 12 and 6 is identical first, and since they're not identical, it'll return False. THey they check the next one, if 3 and 3 is identical, and since it's identical, they'll return True.

You can use [itertools.zip_longest](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.zip_longest) to iterate multiple sequences and have each of their nth item at a time e.g. in your lists would be 12 and 6, then 3 and 3, then 45 and 30, and so on.

- This would also handle the scenario when the lists have differing lengths.

```py
from itertools import zip_longest

list_1 = [12, 3, 45, 2, 50]
list_2 = [6, 3, 30, 5, 50]

result = [
    value_1 == value_2
    for value_1, value_2 in zip_longest(list_1, list_2)
]
print(result)
```

Output:

```py
[False, True, False, False, True]
```

Here, you can see that (1-based numbering) the 2nd (value of 3) and the 5th (value of 50) items are identical thus the only ones that are `True`.